# Apache Mina Android Failed to connect

Tags: java, android, apache-mina

I made a client-server application in Apache Mina. The server will run on Windows and the client on Android 4.1. When testing the client locally (code is called in a stand-alone Java application) all works ok. On device it says that it could not connect to server. Both client and servers are located on the same, local network. Do you have any ideas why this behavior.

It could be because permissions? I put

`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"`

`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"`
but with no effect.

**Server code**

```
        final IoAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();
        acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());
        acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new ObjectSerializationCodecFactory()));
        acceptor.setHandler(ioHandler);
        acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(2048);
        acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

**Client code**

```
        this.connector = new NioSocketConnector();
        connector.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(2048);
        LoggingFilter restrictedLoggingFilter = new LoggingFilter();
        connector.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", restrictedLoggingFilter);
        connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new ObjectSerializationCodecFactory()));
        connector.setHandler(handler);

        final InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
        final ConnectFuture future = connector.connect(remoteAddress);
        future.awaitUninterruptibly(2000);

        if (!future.isConnected()) {
            throw new Exception("Could not connect");
        }

        session = future.getSession();
        session.getConfig().setUseReadOperation(true);
```

Used port 5000
Used IP 192.168.1.5 (server IP)